# Tag for rejected questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should a tag be created for "closed"/"rejected" questions? It might make sense to have them tagged if they're being kept for archival purposes—it would also mean that a question [like this one on Win32 worms](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/problems-with-worm-win32-fipp-infection) won't have a tag about "optimization," when the question has absolutely nothing to do with optimization. . . .

Answer (score 3):

No.

Closed questions can already be searched, by searching for "closed:1". Most closed questions are kept around. If we really want to have a "this question was closed for historical reasons" banner like Stack Overflow, we should submit a feature request.

Closed questions that are way off-topic, like the Win32 worm question, should be deleted. Thank you for reminding me to do that.

Comment: Okay. Didn't realize that capability was already in the system. Never mind then. :-)